# Fancyhdr geometry correct with pagestyle but not thispagestyle

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, geometry

I'm trying to generate a document that has two different possible headers, one for the first page of the document and the first page of sections, and one for all other pages. All pages should have footers that give the page number.

I'm using `fancyhdr` and have defined page styles associated with each header, and the problem I'm running into is how to correct for the fact that the header for first pages is larger than that for the others. When I switch from one to the other, I have to force the geometry to be recalculated, most notably so that the footer doesn't get pushed off the page when I increase the headheight. I've put the recalculation of the geometry in the page style definition so that they're called together, and if I call `\pagestyle{either style}`, I get the expected results.

The part where I'm lost is that I'd like to be able to use `\thispagestyle` for the first pages of each section, and when I try to do so I get the appropriate heading but not the appropriate geometry.

Here's a MWE that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\fancypagestyle{firstpages}{%
  \newgeometry{includeheadfoot, left=1cm, right=1cm, top=.5cm, bottom = 1cm, headheight=57pt}
  \rhead{Long header\\line2\\line3\\line4}
  \cfoot{\thepage} 
  }

\fancypagestyle{others}{%
  \newgeometry{includeheadfoot, left=1cm, right=1cm, top=.5cm, bottom=1cm, headheight=15pt}
  \lhead{}
  \chead{}
  \rhead{Normal header}
  \cfoot{\thepage}
  }

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{firstpages}
Text under big header

\pagebreak
\pagestyle{others}
Text under little header

\pagebreak
\thispagestyle{firstpages}
Text under big header

\pagebreak
Text under little header

\pagebreak
\pagestyle{firstpages}
Text under big header

\end{document}
```

The pages where the style is defined by `\pagestyle` (1, 2, 4, 5) are fine, but on page 3, where `\thispagestyle` is used, the boxes associated with the geometry don't shift and (I think as a consequence) the footer is pushed off the page.

I haven't found a description of differences between `\pagestyle` and `\thispagestyle` that I'd expect to be causing this behaviour, but clearly something is. Is there a way of making this work? (Alternatively, I'd be happy to hear of a different way to make just the first page of an otherwise-undemarcated section differ from the rest of the section without a known page-break location.) I'm not a very experienced Latex user, so let me know if I'm overlooking anything obvious.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think it's a good idea to use `\newgeometry` as part of a pagestyle. Anyway, `fancyhdr` expects the head height to be the same across the document.

Comment: Do you have suggestions for how to handle the case of multiple head heights then? (I'm trying to imitate an existing document, so the closer to matching it I can be the better.)

Comment: There should be no need to change the headheight. Set it to the height needed for the small header, let the large header stick out of it  and move the section/text on the pages with large header down with a simple \vspace.

Comment: Okay, that does work. I had discarded that idea a while ago because I couldn't figure out how to keep fancyhdr from changing the headheight itself, but that's a solved issue now that I know how to look. I'm still confused by the differences between \pagestyle and \thispagestyle, but that can be a problem for next time.

Comment: `\thispagestyle` is only for the current page, afterwards the old page style before is used, i.e. `\thispagestyle` 'eclipses' the outer page style for a 'moment', applies its own settings, the page is shipped out, the old pagestyle is reactivated.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: A call to `\pagestyle` is executed immediately. A call to `\thispagestyle` is only executed as part of the page shipout routine - that ensures that it will supersede whatever `\pagestyle` might be in effect (or be called after `\thispagestyle` on the same page). For that reason, `\pagestyle` shows the desired result, while `\thispagestyle` doesn't - the page, with its dimensions, have already been assembled.

From the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co):

```
\def\pagestyle#1{%
  \@ifundefined{ps@#1}%
    \undefinedpagestyle
    {\@nameuse{ps@#1}}}
\def\thispagestyle#1{%
  \@ifundefined{ps@#1}%
    \undefinedpagestyle
    {\global\@specialpagetrue\gdef\@specialstyle{#1}}}
```

Note how `\pagestyle{<style>}` calls `\@nameuse{ps@<style>}`, while `\thispagestyle{<style>}` just sets a flag - `\@specialpagetrue` and stores the style in `\@specialstyle`. Only later (as part of `\@outputpage`) is the style applied.